# Part of console app stops working after a few minutes C#. Please copy and paste this console app code for yourself

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task, console-application

The app below "runs" for about 2 minutes after entering an IP address (not sure the exact time) and then "stops" running. By "stops" I mean it is stuck on this line when i pause the debugger after it has run for 10 minutes:

Any idea why?

**EDIT:**

You can copy and past the code below into a console app and it will run. It takes a couple minutes, and after a few iterations, it (usually) gets stuck on message 161.

**EDIT:**
The sending portion of this application stops working. But the listening for UDP continues as expected. See accepted answer on why this is happneing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace UDPTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string ip;
        static UDPSender sender;
        static UDPListener listener;
        private static bool _quitFlag = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter '1' to listen for UDP messages or '2' to send UDP messages, or 3 for both sending and receiving");
            int choice = 3;
            //if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
            //{
                int port = 10001;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter YOUR IP address (include periods)");
                ip = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 3: // send and receive from same terminal
                        Task taskReceive = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            listener = new UDPListener(ip, port);
                            listener.StartListener();
                        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                        taskReceive.Start();

                        sender = new UDPSender(ip, port);
                        sender.SendUDPContinuously(100);

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("the input entered was not understood" + Environment.NewLine);
                        break;
                }
            //}
            //else
            //{
                //Console.WriteLine("Invalid integer input");
            //}
            //Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
        }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class UDPSender
    {
        private Socket s;
        private static byte sequenceNumber = 255;
        private IPAddress toIpAddress;
        private int portNumber;
        private byte lastOctet;         // first part of message byte array
        public UDPSender(string ipAddress, int portNumber)
        {
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
                ProtocolType.Udp);
            toIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
            lastOctet = toIpAddress.GetAddressBytes()[3];
            this.portNumber = portNumber;
        }

        public void SendUDPOnce()
        {
            byte[] sendbuf = new byte[4];
            BuildByteMessage(lastOctet, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PF"), sendbuf); // I can refactor this to just take a CommandParameters.BytesAndCommandEnum
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(toIpAddress, portNumber);
            s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sender: Message sent to the broadcast address: " + toIpAddress + Environment.NewLine + "Sender: contents (first byte is IP_Octet, second is sequenceNumber): " + string.Join(",", sendbuf));
        }

        public void SendUDPContinuously(int delayMiliseconds)
        {
            Timer timerstuff = new Timer(sate => SendUDPOnce(), null, 0, delayMiliseconds);
        }

        private void BuildByteMessage(byte lastOctet, byte[] parameterCommand, byte[] destination)
        {
            byte sequenceNum = CreateNextSequenceByte();
            destination[0] = lastOctet;
            destination[1] = sequenceNum;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(parameterCommand, 0, destination, 2, parameterCommand.Length);
        }

        public byte CreateNextSequenceByte()
        {
            if (sequenceNumber != 255)
            {
                sequenceNumber++;
            }
            else
            {
                sequenceNumber = 0;
            }
            return sequenceNumber;
        }
    }

}

namespace UDPTest2
{
    public class UDPListener
    {
        string ipAddress;
        int listenPort;

        public UDPListener(string ipAddress, int listenPort)
        {
            this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
            this.listenPort = listenPort;
        }

        public void StartListener()
        {
            bool done = false;

            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), listenPort);

            try
            {
                while (!done)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Receiver: Waiting for broadcast...");

                    //First byte of the received message is the ASCII Mesage type flag: Q=Data, M=Metric, F=Fault. Second byte is the U8 sequence number. Third byte on is the actual data. 
                    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    byte[] data = new byte[bytes.Length - 2];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 2, data, 0, bytes.Length - 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Receiver: broadcast from {0} :\nReceiver: {1}\nReceiver: contents of each byte: " + string.Join(", ", bytes),
                        groupEP.ToString(),
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)); // Or Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you press a key in the console?

Comment: Nothing happens from pressing a random key, but Ctr+C still works as expected (that's what I'm checking for before changing the _quitFlag variable). One thing i noticed if I uncomment the long Console.WriteLine in the while loop of the UDPListener class, the app quits much sooner.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, Of course it waits at `Console.ReadKey` that's what is meant to happen. It would be helpful if you could provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done. The above can be copied into a console app to reproduce the problem. I tried to make this as close to the original as I could without the specifics that do not matter. This can be pasted into one file (the "Program.cs")

Comment: Which choice no are you entering?

Comment: Changed the app to not require that. It was 3

Comment: Pause the application in VS and see where on which line it stucks

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It gets to Console.ReadLine(); but it was there even when the app was working since the sender was in the background Timer. I'm thinking that the sender is stopping sending messages for some reason?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have verified that the listener portion of this app is still able to receive other messages from other UDP packets, it just is not sending new ones out. This is even when the app is "stuck" on Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timer timerstuff` is a local variable. It could be disposed by the GC at some point. Make it a field to make it permanent and to keep it alive.

```
public class UDPSender
{
    private Timer _timerstuff;

    ...

    public void SendUDPContinuously(int delayMiliseconds)
    {
        _timerstuff = new Timer(sate => SendUDPOnce(), null, 0, delayMiliseconds);
    }                           

    ...
}
```

See: [Automatic memory management and garbage collection: Releasing Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/gc#releasing-memory) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. But what this means is that all thread, tasks, timers etc that need to stay alive would have to be fields or global's rather than local variables; is this statement correct?

Comment: Every object which has to stay alive must be reachable. It can well be a local variable, as long as the calling method is alive (like `Program.Main`) and the variable is in scope. It can also be a captured variable in a lambda expression that is alive.

Comment: @Oliver One thing I noticed is that the Task taskReceive = new Task(() ... object, is that even though this is NOT a field, the task does not get cleaned up by GC when the code goes outside of the scope of the switch statement. Why is this an exception to the rule, but the timer is not. Maybe this is just random chance?

Comment: This depends on how the compiler works. Even if the variable is not in scope in C# terms, it might be kept on the stack or in a register. But this could change in future compiler versions. It could also be that a reference is kept in a Task pool as long as the Task is running. I would widen its scope to be sure.